# What Multiple contributors means in Drupal Translations site?

Tags: community-official-site

I just notice that when you go to the different Drupal Translations sites (for example the [French site](https://localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/fr)) there is a user named ***Multiple contributors*** but I can't figure out what this means, is a user or a contribution that is made from a different site?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Working with translation files offline](https://www.drupal.org/node/314231) documentation under the **Contributing back to the community** header:

> When you have finished, contribute the translation back to
>   localize.drupal.org by importing the file on the translation team user
>   interface. Translations will either be attributed to you or "Multiple
>   contributors" depending on which option you choose. ***"Multiple
>   contributors" is a special account you can use if multiple people
>   worked on the translations being imported and singling out one
>   contributor for attribution would not be correct.***